# Scrapy conditional crawling

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, scrapy

my HTML code contains a number of divs with mostly similar structure ... below is the code excerpt containing 2 such divs

```
<!-- 1st Div start --> 

<div class="outer-container">
<div class="inner-container">
<a href="www.xxxxxx.com"></a>
<div class="abc xyz" title="verified"></div>
<div class="mody">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-12">
                <h2><a class="mheading primary h4" href="/c/my-llc"><strong>Top Dude, LLC</strong></a></h2>
                <div class="mvsdfm casmhrn" itemprop="address">
                    <span itemprop="Address">1223 Industrial Blvd</span><br>
                    <span itemprop="Locality">Paris</span>, <span itemprop="Region">BA</span> <span itemprop="postalCode">123345</span>
                </div>
                <div class="hidden-device-xs" itemprop="phone" rel="mainPhone">
                    (800) 845-0000
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<!-- 2nd Div start -->

<div class="outer-container">
<div class="inner-container">
<a href="www.yyyyyy.com"></a>
<div class="mody">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-12">
                <h2><a class="mheading primary h4" href="/c/my-llc"><strong>Fat Dude, LLC</strong></a></h2>
                <div class="mvsdfm casmhrn" itemprop="address">
                    <span itemprop="Address">7890 Business St</span><br>
                    <span itemprop="Locality">Tokyo</span>, <span itemprop="Region">MA</span> <span itemprop="postalCode">987655</span>
                </div>
                <div class="hidden-device-xs" itemprop="phone" rel="mainPhone">
                    (800) 845-0000
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**So here is what I want Scrapy to do** ...

**If** the div with *class="outer-container"* contains another div with *title="verified"* like in the 1st div above, it should go to the URL above it (i.e www.xxxxxx.com) and fetch some other feilds on that page.

**If** there is no div containing *title="verified"*, like in 2nd div above, it should fetch all the data under *div class="mody"*. i.e. company name (Fat Dude, LLC), address, city, state etc ... and NOT follow the url (i.e. www.yyyyy.com)

So how do I apply this condition/logic in Scrapy crawler. I was thinking of  using BeautifulSoup, but not sure ....

**What have I tried so far ....**

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'dknfetch'
    start_urls = ['http://www.xxxxxx.com/scrapy/all-listing']
    allowed_domains = ['www.xxxxx.com']
    def parse(self, response):
            hxs = Selector(response)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(response.body, 'lxml')
            nf = NewsFields()
            cName = soup.find_all("a", class_="mheading primary h4")
            addrs = soup.find_all("span", itemprop_="Address")
            loclity = soup.find_all("span", itemprop_="Locality")
            region = soup.find_all("span", itemprop_="Region")
            post = soup.find_all("span", itemprop_="postalCode")

            nf['companyName'] = cName[0]['content']
            nf['address'] = addrs[0]['content']
            nf['locality'] = loclity[0]['content']
            nf['state'] = region[0]['content']
            nf['zipcode'] = post[0]['content']
             yield nf
            for url in hxs.xpath('//div[@class="inner-container"]/a/@href').extract():
             yield Request(url, callback=self.parse)
```

Ofcourse, the above code returns and crawl all the URL's under the *div class="inner-container"* as there is no conditional crawling specified in this code, becuase I don't know where/how to set it.

If anyone has done something similar before, please share. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No need to use BeautifulSoup, Scrapy comes with it's own selector capabilities (also released separately as [*parsel*](https://parsel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)). Let's use your HTML to make an example:

```
html = u"""
<!-- 1st Div start --> 
<div class="outer-container">
<div class="inner-container">
<a href="www.xxxxxx.com"></a>
<div class="abc xyz" title="verified"></div>
<div class="mody">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-12">
                <h2><a class="mheading primary h4" href="/c/my-llc"><strong>Top Dude, LLC</strong></a></h2>
                <div class="mvsdfm casmhrn" itemprop="address">
                    <span itemprop="Address">1223 Industrial Blvd</span><br>
                    <span itemprop="Locality">Paris</span>, <span itemprop="Region">BA</span> <span itemprop="postalCode">123345</span>
                </div>
                <div class="hidden-device-xs" itemprop="phone" rel="mainPhone">
                    (800) 845-0000
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- 2nd Div start -->
<div class="outer-container">
<div class="inner-container">
<a href="www.yyyyyy.com"></a>
<div class="mody">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-12">
                <h2><a class="mheading primary h4" href="/c/my-llc"><strong>Fat Dude, LLC</strong></a></h2>
                <div class="mvsdfm casmhrn" itemprop="address">
                    <span itemprop="Address">7890 Business St</span><br>
                    <span itemprop="Locality">Tokyo</span>, <span itemprop="Region">MA</span> <span itemprop="postalCode">987655</span>
                </div>
                <div class="hidden-device-xs" itemprop="phone" rel="mainPhone">
                    (800) 845-0000
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
"""

from parsel import Selector
sel = Selector(text=html)
for div in sel.css('.outer-container'):
    if div.css('div[title="verified"]'):
        url = div.css('a::attr(href)').extract_first()
        print 'verified, follow this URL:', url
    else:
        nf = {}
        nf['companyName'] = div.xpath('string(.//h2)').extract_first()
        nf['address'] = div.css('span[itemprop="Address"]::text').extract_first()
        nf['locality'] = div.css('span[itemprop="Locality"]::text').extract_first()
        nf['state'] = div.css('span[itemprop="Region"]::text').extract_first()
        nf['zipcode'] = div.css('span[itemprop="postalCode"]::text').extract_first()
        print 'not verified, extracted item is:', nf
```

The result for the previous snippet is:

```
verified, follow this URL: www.xxxxxx.com
not verified, extracted item is: {'zipcode': u'987655', 'state': u'MA', 'address': u'7890 Business St', 'locality': u'Tokyo', 'companyName': u'Fat Dude, LLC'}
```

But in Scrapy you don't even need to instantiate the `Selector` class, there is a shortcut available in the `response` object passed to callbacks. Also, you shouldn't be subclassing `CrawlSpider`, just the regular `Spider` class is enough. Putting it all together:

```
from scrapy import Spider, Request
from myproject.items import NewsFields

class MySpider(Spider):
    name = 'dknfetch'
    start_urls = ['http://www.xxxxxx.com/scrapy/all-listing']
    allowed_domains = ['www.xxxxx.com']

    def parse(self, response):
        for div in response.selector.css('.outer-container'):
            if div.css('div[title="verified"]'):
                url = div.css('a::attr(href)').extract_first()
                yield Request(url)
            else:
                nf = NewsFields()
                nf['companyName'] = div.xpath('string(.//h2)').extract_first()
                nf['address'] = div.css('span[itemprop="Address"]::text').extract_first()
                nf['locality'] = div.css('span[itemprop="Locality"]::text').extract_first()
                nf['state'] = div.css('span[itemprop="Region"]::text').extract_first()
                nf['zipcode'] = div.css('span[itemprop="postalCode"]::text').extract_first()
                yield nf
```

I would suggest you to get familar with Parsel's API: https://parsel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html

Happy scraping!